# How to run an Android app with parameters using Terminal?

Tags: android

Is it possible to start an Android application with different parameters (e.g. boolean or int type) from command prompt and how I can catch these parameters in my activity class? What is the best way to do that?

I want start application this way but with parameters which I can using in code:

adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.XXX.xxx/com.XXX.xxx.Main

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following parameters:

```
[-e|--es <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE> ...]
[--esn <EXTRA_KEY> ...]
[--ez <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_BOOLEAN_VALUE> ...]
[--ei <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE> ...]
[--el <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_LONG_VALUE> ...]
[--eu <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_URI_VALUE> ...]
[--eia <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_INT_VALUE...]]
[--ela <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_LONG_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_LONG_VALUE...]]
```

For example:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.XXX.xxx/com.XXX.xxx.Main --es STRING_PAR_NAME stringParameterValue
```

They are accessible from the `Intent`, used to start activity, via `get[Type]Extra()` - e.g. [getStringExtra(String name)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra%28java.lang.String%29). You can get it using [getIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent%28%29) if activity was just launched or in `Intent` parameter in [onNewIntent(Intent intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) if activity is already running.